# Issues with Importing python files within a Django Project

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems with importing python files within my project. I've clearly set up a file named testing.py within a folder called api, which is the same directory where my views.py file. When I import testing within views.py, I keep getting an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'". I'm not sure if I need to create an init.py file here for the module, but it should be importing without any error regardless. Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

views.py file within api:

```
import http
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
import testing


# Create your views here.


def test(request) :

    return HttpResponse(testing.testFunction())
```

testing.py file within api:

```
def testFunction():

    return "This is a test"
```

Comment: If it is in your API folder, it should be `from api.testing import testFunction`

Answer (score 0):

If it is in your API folder, it should be `from api.testing import testFunction`